# editor.editor.document undefined in Firefox after CKEDITOR.on instanceReady

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, darkmode

I am trying to apply a css class to the html element of the ckeditor content in order to support our CSS custom property driven light/dark themeswitcher. The demo below successfully adds the class in Chromium based browsers but in Firefox, the

```
editor.editor.document.$
```

object is undefined even though a console.log of the editor object shows that it is defined.

Any ideas why this isn't working in Firefox?

I'm pretty new to CKEDITOR development, so if there's actually a much better way to interact with the iframe's HTML element, I'm happy to switch to that. I know there's bodyClass https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-bodyClass but unfortunately that doesn't work for us.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>
      /**
      * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2020, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
      * For licensing, see https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
      */

      CKEDITOR.on('instanceLoaded', function(editor){
          console.log(editor);
          if (typeof editor.editor.document !== 'undefined'){
              editor.editor.document.$.documentElement.classList.add('sakai-dark-theme');
          }
          
          editor.editor.on('afterCommandExec', function(evt){
              if (evt.data.name === 'source'
                  && typeof evt.editor.document !== 'undefined'
                  && typeof evt.editor.document.$ !== 'undefined') {
                      evt.editor.document.$.documentElement.classList.add('sakai-dark-theme');
              }
          })
      });
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm testing this on PopOS 20.04 Firefox 83.0

Comment: It's possible that Firefox may just not have everything loaded in the instanceLoaded method. Maybe trying the instanceReady method would get this to work, or adding a delay/retry to the check here?